# Unable to boot from a bootable USB drive on a machine where Win 10 is installed already to be able to start installing Linux

Tags: arch-linux, windows, dual-boot, uefi

I'm trying to replace win 10 with Arch. Now only Windows 10 is installed.

I've created a bootable usb:

```
# dd bs=4M if=/path/to/archlinux.iso of=/dev/sdb status=progress && sync
```

Then I chose a temporary booting device to be my usb device with Arch and the end of the story: it showed me a black screen for a couple of seconds and then the menu "Choose temporary booting device" again. I've tried the same action a few times and each time it still showed me the black screen for a couple of seconds and returned back to the menu.

I haven't changed anything in uefi menu, maybe it's the reason? But what should I change?
Or is the reason due to something  else?

Note I want to remove Windows 10, not create a dual boot system.

Comment: Go to your UEFI menu and disable "safe boot".  If you bought this machine with windows 10 pre-installed it is likely locked to MS windows 10 by the safe boot feature.  (Note that "safe boot" has nothing to do with actual safety.)

Comment: Depending on your UEFI menu, "safe boot" may be listed as "secure boot".   In either case @grochmal is correct there is nothing secure or safe about that feature.

Answer (score 0):

By default Windows 10 use a GPT partition table in UEFI mode. So, please use UEFI boot to install your Archlinux. If you setup is configured to SECURE BOOT, you have to disable and the bootable USB will start.

Maybe there are some other issues related to your bootable USB, because we need the USB drive are using a ***FAT format file*** (I already have this kind of issue) because in UEFI mode the */boot* partition have to be in a FAT filesystem. The `dd` command just makes a bit-to-bit copy of the file, but doesnt format the USB drive. So, format the USB drive using a FAT format file and after that use `dd` command like you did before

```
dd bs=4M if=/path/to/archlinux.iso of=/dev/sdx status=progress oflag=sync
```

By doing this way, and disable your SECURE BOOT, everything will work fine.

Comment: That last part of your answer is completely wrong. The `dd` command overwrites the USB stick with an image. The image contains a partition table and filesystems. So anything you have previously done to the USB stick - including formatting it - is overwritten and replaced.

Comment: It's also way more efficient to use `cat /path/to/archlinux.iso >/dev/sdx`. The `dd` command should be your tool of last resort, not your first.

Comment: I know that `dd` create the partition table from the iso, but I'm not sure about the filesystem. Anyway I will try again.